# Azure Portal Directory is not been displayed in appcenter

Tags: android, azure, azureportal, visual-studio-app-center

I have appcenter and azure portal account.
I do have directory on azure portal and application on appcenter.
But it still does not work.
Please help.

Below is the steps which i tried.

- 1) login into app center
- 2) Click on account settings on right side

  3) Click azure  [image: This get appear]

  4)Click + button [image: This page appear.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an issue with Microsoft's App Center. Go ahead and ask the Help (floating button in the bottom right corner of MS App Center) and tell them about the issue. They should be able to help you. I have been able to connect my account to Azure before, and it mentions for you "authentication failed". So it should be specific to your usage.

Comment: yes it was some microsoft's app center error. it works very next day